# How to connect to http://localhost/magento to complete Magento Community Edition ver1.9.2.4 installation?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

After installing MySQL Community Server and successfully creating magento database, I still cannot connect to finish the magento installation or even view the Magento Installation Wizard.

I typed this into the command line:

```
create database magento;
```

Gave me ERR: 1820 (HY000), but I overcame this with:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

And then quit MySQL.

Then I downloaded the Magento Software Community Edition ver 1.9.2.4 tar.gz, I moved the files to /Library/WebServer/Documents and tried to launch a browser on http://localhost/magento, IP address/magento, and cannot finish the setup since localhost is unable to connect.

I was following this tutorial but now I'm stuck at the 8:00 mark:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJRaCzPUqic

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the MySQL socket file path in your php.ini - when connecting to localhost MySQL, PHP would look for the socket first, and the most recent distributions of MySQL (say MacPorts' one) disable networking in MySQL settings by default.

Either enable networking in your MySQL settings (so that 127.0.0.1 can be reached by PHP), use 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" in database credentials (host), or amend php.ini to set the default mysql socket to the correct path on your system.